# android spinner dropdown list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i want to make dropdown list like below,

[image]

i'm trying to with sherlockactivity and spinner. but i didn't know how.

here is my simple code but ... this is not what i wanted

java

```
final Spinner spinnerSelectmenu = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_filemenu_selectmenu);
    String[] items = {"", "menu1", "menu2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMenuList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    spinnerMenuList.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSelectmenu.setAdapter(spinnerMenuList);
```

xml

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_filemenu_selectmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: I think that is not spinner...

Answer (score 2):

`android:spinnerMode="dropdown"` seems to be the right thing, however AFAIK it is only available from API 11 onwards. 
Other sources say that you need to use a Holo theme to make your code being displayed as dropdown. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560603/1666456