# Dropdown spinner android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm developing app in Android 2.3.3 having spinner always opening in Dialog mode .I want to open it as in Drop Down mode . Is there any customization available in android 2.3.3 to open it as Drop Down mode ?

Comment: Check this link: http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/07/dropdown-mode-for-spinner-in-android-2-3-3-and-higher/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dropdown spinners for android below android 4.0 But you can use this [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) as dropdown list [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864180) or lib [HoloEverywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858388) Hope it helps :)