# I am using spinners, I want to change the style in which they open

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want the spinner to open in a popup manner instead of the list manner which i am getting right now. I have tried changing the theme as well. The spinner worked in the popup manner in the lower version devices. What can i do?thanks in advance.
I want the opposite of what problem is discussed here [Android: Change Spinner Dropdown view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560432/android-change-spinner-dropdown-view)

Comment: then use AlertDialog with Adapter instead ...

Answer (score 0):

On your xml file, set

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

on your spinner.